# Why does string this cause some terminal windows to close. ".(:2)"

Tags: bash, shell, intellij-idea, terminal, pipe

I wrote a script and ran into an odd behavior. Some terminal windows it is run in would suddenly close before the script was completed running.

After a few hours of investigation I tracked the issue down to this line output

```
init: Command 'mount_all /fstab.ranchu' action=fs (/init.ranchu.rc:2) returned 0 took 1805ms.
```

After some more refinement I determined this is the minimum sequence needed to regenerate this problem.

```
.(:2)
```

If I type this sequence in a terminal tab in Intellij code editor that tab will, after about a second, close itself. More frustrating this problem
is occurring when this script is run as part of my build/CI system.

It does not impact all terminals, for example `Gnome-terminal` and `xterm` do not have any issues with that sequence.

The digit `2` in that string can actually be any integer up to 9 digits long and it will cause the issue.

I suspect this sequence might be a terminal control sequence but I didn't find anything like that in my research.

Another odd thing is that I sometimes my script output will stall stall(buffer, I can see the script still working) for longer than expected periods.

I found this set of commands solved the buffering issue and the problem with the closing terminal but I would like to know what is going on

```
./example.sh |& stdbuf -eL -oL sed -s 's/:\([0-9][0-9]*)\)/:_\1/'
```

`example.sh` looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '.(:2)'
```

`stdbuf` configures the buffer that is used for the pipe/`|&`.
The sed statement takes `.(:2)` and turns it into `.(:_2)` which seems to prevent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Looking into this a bit more. Turns out the CI failures were caused by something else that just happened to occur roughly the spot I mentioned above.

After upgrading and restarting IntelliJ the problem disappeared there too.

I am going to blame a random glitch.